# Birch reduction in diethyl ether

Tags: organic-reduction

I wanna ask, why I can't find any experiment using amonia dissolved in diethyl ether. You could bypass need of cooling the amonia under it boiling point by gassing the amonia to diethyl ether. Why it wouldn't work? Any experiments using dissolved amonia in solvent at normal temperature?? Thanks.

Comment: The reduction of enones with Li bronze in ether has been  accomplished. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00418a024

Answer (score 3):

If you can find another solvent in which to run the reaction, you don't need the ammonia as a solute.  The Birch reduction is a reaction with solvated electrons, not with ammonia, and the key is identifying a solvent that can hold the solvated electrons for reaction with the substrate.

Many solvents that are liquid at room temperature and atmospheric pressure can harbor these solvated electrons.  In fact even water does so, but (in addition to being a relatively poor solvent for many organic compounds) its highly polarized hydrogen atoms bonded to oxygen react so quickly with the electrons that the latter are gone before they can get to the intended substrate.  Solvents such as THF or ethylenediamine, in which the hydrogen atoms are bonded to carbon and nitrogen atoms and are less apt to be transferred as protons, are the ones that work.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_reduction):

> Since liquid ammonia has to be condensed into the flask and has to evaporate overnight after the reaction is complete, the whole procedure can be quite troublesome and time-consuming. However, alternative solvents have been employed, such as THF[1][[2](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo0257593)] as well as a mixture of n-propylamine and ethylenediamine,[[3](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo0008136)] both with comparable results.

**Cited references**

1.
Ecsery, Zoltan & Muller, Miklos (1961). "Reduction vitamin D2 with alkaly metals". *Magyar Kémiai Folyóirat.* **67**: 330–332.

2.
Donohoe, Timothy J. & House, David (2002). "Ammonia Free Partial Reduction of Aromatic Compounds Using Lithium Di-tert-butylbiphenyl (LiDBB)". *Journal of Organic Chemistry.* **67** (14): 5015–5018. doi:10.1021/jo0257593. PMID 12098328.

3.
Garst, Michael E.; Lloyd J.; Shervin; N. Andrew; Natalie C.; Alfred A.; et al. (2000). "Reductions with Lithium in Low Molecular Weight Amines and Ethylenediamine". *Journal of Organic Chemistry.* **65** (21): 7098–7104. doi:10.1021/jo0008136. PMID 11031034